# Filter data in form request in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have generated new form Request for the controller, but I do not know how to filter data before there will handle in the validator and so on.

**Are there some native solutions in Laravel for this case?**

```
class TestRequest extends FormRequest
{

  /**
   * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function authorize()
  {
      return true;
  }

  /**
   * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules()
  { 


    return [
       "title" => "required|string",
       "order" => "required|integer"
    ];
  }

}

class TestController extends Controller
{ 
     public function store(TestRequest $request, $chapterId)
     {
       // some business logic
     }
}
```

There is some [solution](https://laravel-news.com/request-data-validator-improvements) in Laravel 5.5 but in this example author uses 
`validate` for filtering data from request, **but I need to use filter inside TestRequest**

```
 $data = $this->validate(request(), [
         //...
    ]); // I can't use this inside TestRequest
```

Comment: can you post your controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package: https://github.com/mikicaivosevic/laravel-filters

It's allows you to filter request values before validation...

```
<?php

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest {

//Filter
public function filters()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'lower',
        'id'   => 'int',
    ];
}

//...
```

}

- Convert $request->name value into lowercase.
- Conert $request->id value into integer.